# Extract URL from Hyperlink inside source code of a website

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to parse PDF files from [Xtremepapers](https://papers.xtremepape.rs/CAIE/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/):

[image: HTML Source code at:]

However, the `href` attribute in the anchor tag contains a sort of HyperLink to the download page for that particular PDF, instead of the direct download link.

I want help in extracting the download link and saving it to my hard drive through some Python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm pretty new at this, so this might be bumpy. But it looks like you are using the inspect element and not developer tools.

If you use developer tools, hit refresh to the website and then click the mathematics name, you will see the real html. and you can see each pdf is linked like this:

```
 a_tag = <a class="autoindex_a" href="9709_2007_syllabus.pdf">
<img width="16" height="16" alt="[pdf]" src="/images/icons/pdf.png" />
9709_2007_syllabus.pdf </a> 

end_url = a_tag.get('href', None)

print(end_url)

>>9709_2007_syllabus.pdf
```

Then you just need to attach that bit to the url of the website 'https://papers.xtremepape.rs/CAIE/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/'

```
full_url = 'https://papers.xtremepape.rs/CAIE/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/' + end_url

print(full_url)  >>https://papers.xtremepape.rs/CAIE/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_2007_syllabus.pdf
```

So you end with this link which takes you to thd pdf:
https://papers.xtremepape.rs/CAIE/AS%20and%20A%20Level/Mathematics%20(9709)/9709_2007_syllabus.pdf

Comment: I didn't think that simply adding the file's name to the end of the page's URL would lead to the download page. Thank you. It works now.